# Get BitBucket Pull Request's, Id only

Tags: bitbucket-api

I have a CI teamcity build where we will be using Bitbucket API to create a pull request. The Build chain is designed in such a way that a comment "build this" to the PR will trigger the build chain. At present this process (creating PR and adding comment) is done manually; and we are trying to automate this.

We were able to successfully create the PR via PR;

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u sysAccount:sysPasswd https://stash.org.com:1234/rest/api/1.0/projects/MyProjName/repos/MyRepoName/pull-requests -d '{ "title": "Pull Request Test", "description": "My PR", "state": "OPEN", "open": true, "closed": false, "fromRef": { "id": "refs/heads/myFeatureBranch", "repository": { "slug": "MyPrivateRepo", "name": "MyPrivateRepo", "project": { "key": "~SystemAccount" } } }, "toRef": { "id": "refs/heads/master", "repository": { "slug": "PublicRepoName", "name": "PublicRepoName", "project": { "key": "TeamPrjName" } } }, "locked": false, "reviewers": [] }'
```

And another API call to add comments:

```
curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u sysAccount:sysPasswd https://stash.org.com:1234/rest/api/1.0/projects/MyProjName/repos/MyRepoName/pull-requests/12345/comments -d '{ "text": "build this" }'
```

However how can we retrieve the id (i.e 12345 in this example.). We can get the full JSON response for this PR; however i just need the pullRequestId

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get what the actual problem here is. With the first API call you already get the ID of the new Pull Request out of the Json Response, don't you? Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pull Request Notifier](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket) and construct a URL like:

```
https://stash.org.com:1234/rest/api/1.0/projects/MyProjName/repos/MyRepoName/pull-requests/${PULL_REQUEST_ID}/comments
```

Comment: Thanks, however i do not have admin access to the Bitbucket server. Hence adding a plugin, is unfortunately not an option. I suppose i wold need to do it via a custom program, OR using any parameters in Bitbucket API to get the ID